# get reference to the appended item and append some other item to the previously appended item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Theory:

It's classifieds website each post in the classifieds website has chat icon, if a user click on this button a new chat box will open

```
<div class="box" ><div class="had-container">hi welcom</div></div> //chatbox
```

actually chatbox is appended to

```
<div id="insert"></div>
```

once the chat box is open I am checking whether the user is logged in or not if a user is not logged in I want to append

```
<div class="loggedin">You are not logged in</div>
```

to the chatbox

1.For each post there will be a chat icon,  user can click on chat icon on all posts, so using id or class will not work I need a reference to the appended item.

2.I can use if and else. but I want to try this.

Script:-

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      var item=$("#insert");
      var newBox = '<div class="box" ><div class="had-container">hi welcome</div></div>';
      $("#clickhere").on("click", function(){
        item.append(newBox);
        if(usernotloggedin){
      // problem is here I don't know how to get the previously appended item's reference.          
        }
      })
    });


    </script>

    <div id="insert"></div> 

    <div id="clickhere">clicktoappend</div> //if you click once on this
```

Example:-

```
    <div id="clickhere">clicktoappend</div>
```

if you click once on this

```
<div id="insert"></div>
```

becomes

```
<div id="insert"><div class="box" ><div class="had-container">hi welcome</div></div></div>
```

Now I want to append some elements inside appended item. (I need some kind of reference to appended item so I can manipulate it afterwards.)

Now I want to append the following if the user is not logged in

```
<div class="loggedin">You are logged in</div>
```

to the appended item. so it becomes

```
    <div id="insert"><div class="box" ><div class="had-container">hi welcome</div><div class="loggedin">You are not logged in</div></div></div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want a reference to your `box` right? So at what point do you want to reference it? Like is it on click of something etc... And how do you decide which `box` to append to ? (not coding wise But I am interested to know thought wise.) whats the logic to decide which `box` to grab and manipulate

Comment: @Reddy for example var ref=item.append(newBox); if ref works as a reference it will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for example var ref=item.append(newBox); if ref works as a reference it will be good. –

Since you mentioned this you can easily do this.

`var ref=item.append(newBox).find('.box');`

now your `ref` will have the `<div class="box" >...</div>` in it as a Jquery DOM object

Comment: @scriptkiddie glad to help you.